I need help with interpreting message inscribed please
Can anyone help tell me what this reads? There is more but I can not seem to add more than one picture here


Read top-down from right to left columns - 西域取經历艰辛, 普渡众生传美名.


[西域][取經][历艰辛],

Traveled [to the West] to [obtain the Buddhist scripture] and [endured challenges and hardship]

[普渡][众生][传美名]

[generally enlighten] [the mass] and [leave praise-worthy fame]
It describes the general plot of "Journey to the West"(西遊記)
